# Refresh asp:UpdatePanel when navigating to other panels in the same container

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First off, I'm brand new to ASP.NET so I hope I use the correct terminology. I think that what I have is several asp:UpdatePanels in one ajaxToolKit:TabContainer. One panel has some checkboxes one it, here is the first part of the code for it:

```
<ajaxToolKit:TabPanel ID="MedicaidDataSubTabReadyToBill" runat="server" HeaderText="Ready To Bill">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblReadyToBillMessage" runat="server"  Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:Label>      
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MedicaidDataReadyToBillPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regSchoolYear" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="uxMedicaidDataReadyToBill_SchoolYear" ErrorMessage="*invalid school year format." Font-Size="X-Small"
                                    ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This panel loads some checkboxes, some checked and some not, then I go to another panel in the same container and upload an excel file that should make changes to the database that should affect the check boxes on the first panel. Problem is, when I navigate back to the first panel the changes don't reflect. In order for the changes to show I have to refresh the whole page. Is it possible to have this first panel show the changes without having to refresh the whole page? If so how do I do that? If more code is needed to answer this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `UpdatePanel` (and "ASP.NET AJAX" library in general) is an antiquated technique that's since fallen out of favour - is there a reason you're using it?

Comment: I'm working on a pre-existing web application and I don't know enough about the technologies being used to determine which is antiquated or not.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to update an update panel is simple

```
MedicaidDataReadyToBillPanel.Update();
```

When your code that uploads and does db stuff is finished, add that line. Assuming everything else is working, that's all you need.